# Как работает валидатор ввода в данном методе?

Tags: java, методы

Пытаюсь понять, как работает данное решение с валидатором (вложенный в 'do' while).
Никак не могу понять порядок исполнения кода.

Не понимаю, почему age = s.nextInt(); идет ниже цикла. В каком порядке здесь что выполняется?

```
void setAge() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        while (!s.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Некорректное значение, попробуйте еще раз: ");
            s.next();
        }
        age = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Устанавливается возраст...");
        if (age < 0) {
            System.out.println("Некорректное значение, введите еще раз: ");
        }
        if (age > 150) {
            System.out.println("Слишком большое значение, введите еще раз: ");
        }
    } while (age < 0 || age > 150);
    System.out.println("Вы установили возраст - " + this.age);
}
```

Comment: В какой-то степени все логично. Пока следующее значение не окажется числом выдается сообщение об ошибке. Как только дошли до числа вышли из цикла и записали в age это значение и дальше работаем с этой переменной. Стыдно такое не понять.

Comment: Это все ясно. Мне непонятно, грубо говоря, следующее: на каком моменте инициализируется ввод (не создается объект сканнер, а именно возникает момент, когда надо ввести)? Почему, когда запускается while, он не выводит сразу "Некорректное значение, попробуйте еще раз: " ? Потому что методы NEXT реагируют только на следующий поток ввода? так вот и возник вопрос, где в коде указание на первый ввод. пс. в джаве неделю, извиняюсь за некорректность, которая мне может быть не видна

Comment: Ищите тогда нужный фрагмент кода и приводите его. В рамках этого фрагмента такого кода нет как вы видите. Значит есть другая функция, а может и класс обрабатывающие ввод.

Comment: Сразу не выводится сообщение: "Некорректное значение, попробуйте еще раз" Потому, что вначале строка ввода пуста.

Comment: 1. Создается сканер.

Comment: Порядок выполнение вашего метода: В классе создается экземпляр объекта. Через этот экземпляр вызывается ваш метод имяЭкземпляра.setAge(); Создается экземпляр сканера с именем s. Выполняется вход в цикл do{}while(). Выполняется проверка  второго цикла while (!s.hasNextInt()). Затем "age = s.nextInt();" - выполняется метод сканера и присваивается переменной age. Вы можете поставить перед "age = s.nextInt();"  такой код: System.out.println("Введите возраст..."); А вообще используйте отладчик. Пройдитесь по коду пошагово. Сделайте точки останова и отслеживайте то что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

У вас строка:

```
age = s.nextInt();
```

Входит в цикл:

```
  do {/*тело цикла*/} while (age < 0 || age > 150);
```

Такой цикл выполняется хотя-бы один раз, затем проверяется условие. Кстати условие: "(age < 0)" - это начиная с нуля. Возраст разве может быть равен нулю? В условии наверное нужно поставить: "(age <= 0)".